# mgsub with one pattern but multiple replacements in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

In the string

```
text <- "Poem number one, Poem number two, Poem number three"
```

I want to replace all "Poem"s with different replacements.
I want to get:

```
"First number one, Second number two, Third number three"
```

I tried:

```
mgsub(text, c("Poem","Poem", "Poem"), c("First", "Second", "Third"))
```

But i get:

```
"First number one, First number two, First number three"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an incorrect way of using `mgsub`. The elements in the argument `pattern` are expected to be different (that's what I'm lead to believe from the documentation, anyway. You can do repeated calls to the `sub` function like this:

```
text = "Poem number one, Poem number two, Poem number three"

pattern = c("Poem", "Poem", "Poem")
replacement = c("First", "Second", "Third")

new_text = text
for (i in 1:length(pattern))
    new_text = sub(pattern[i], replacement[i], new_text)

> new_text
[1] "First number one, Second number two, Third number three"
```

`gsub` won't work because it replaces all instances of `pattern` in the first call.